# Help me to find probability

Tags: probability

In a Cafe We have 10 people, we need to choose  5 groups which will consist  of people who have come to meet with each other.
What is the probability that we will choose all of them correctly? ( 5 groups with 2 people in each group who's meeting with each other ).

I got ( 30420 / 10!), Is this correct number?

Comment: What does "meeting with each other" mean?

Comment: I think there are 5 correct pairs of people

Comment: There are $9!! = 9\times 7\times 5\times 3\times 1$ ways in which you can pair off the ten people with one another.  (*Seen by direct application of rule of product: choose who was paired with the youngest person, choose who was paired with the youngest remaining, etc...*).  Only one of those is the "correct" sequence of pairings.  Probability is then $\dfrac{1}{9!!}$

Comment: @JMoravitz Wow, have never seen the $!!$ operator before. Good to know.

Comment: @DonThousand It is referred to as a "double factorial."  [See more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).  There are a number of uses and interesting identities involving double factorials and there are related triple factorials and further extensions for larger stepsizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A easy way to understand it.

$$\frac{5.4.3.2.1}{\binom{10}{2}.\binom{8}{2}.\binom{6}{2}.\binom{4}{2}.\binom{2}{2}}$$

At first choice you have 5 right pair and $\binom{10}{2}$ total pairs , then after choosing a pair you got 4 right pairs left and 8 people left or $\binom{8}{2}$ choices and so on.

Comment: Please tell What is Wrong dear down voter !